# case sensitive search in find query using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

my query is

```
$this->find('first', array('fields' => array('Staticpage.title', 'Staticpage.description'),'conditions' => array('Staticpage.url' => 'AUSTRALIA')));
```

Its display in logs like

```
SELECT `Staticpage`.`title`, `Staticpage`.`description` FROM `staticpages` AS `Staticpage` WHERE `Staticpage`.`url` = 'AUSTRALIA' LIMIT 1
```

But i need to search casesensitive, my static url is 'australia' but i type in any case like 'Australia', 'AUSTRALIA' above query give me result.

So, I just used **BINARY** like

```
$this->find('first', array('fields' => array('Staticpage.title', 'Staticpage.description'),'conditions' => array('BINARY Staticpage.url' => 'AUSTRALIA')));
```

Its display in logs like

```
SELECT `Staticpage`.`title`, `Staticpage`.`description` FROM `staticpages` AS `Staticpage`   WHERE `BINARY` Staticpage.url = 'AUSTRALIA'    LIMIT 1
```

so, its doesn't work.

How can i write query using BINARY in find query?

Comment: This later and less well-named question is answered correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784767/mysql-query-in-cake-php-api

Answer (score 1):

```
array("BINARY(Staticpage.url) LIKE" => "AUSTRALIA")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
array("BINARY Staticpage.url = 'AUSTRALIA'")
```