# MySql query in cake php Api

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.1

for data retrieval i need to use **binary** keyword for  case sensitive search in mysql 
this is the query i want to make

```
    SELECT username FROM users 
WHERE  BINARY first_name LIKE 'eph%'
OR     BINARY last_name LIKE 'eph%'
OR      BINARY username LIKE 'eph%'
```

and this is the query i have made in cakephp without binary

```
$this->User->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('User.username'),
            'conditions' => array("OR" => 
                            array("BINARY User.last_name LIKE" => $search_data."%","BINARY User.username LIKE" => $search_data."%",
                                    "BINARY User.first_name LIKE" => $search_data."%"))
                                            ));
```

can any 1 help me out making the binary query using cakephp api  ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok ... you were almost there. You only need to put the Field in a bracket to tell CakePHP not to deal with the BINARY keyword as a field name

Believe this should work:

```
$this->User->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('User.username'),
        'conditions' => array(
                       "OR" =>array(
                                "BINARY (`User`.`last_name`) LIKE" => $search_data."%",
                                "BINARY (`User`.`username`) LIKE" => $search_data."%",        
                                "BINARY (`User`.`first_name`) LIKE" => $search_data."%"))
                           ));
```

Comment: In my case (Cake 2.3), I also had to remove the space after `BINARY`, so Cake wouldn't escape the word.